# Cannot get return from module in nodejs + node-mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I got the following code on my localhost:

/model/company.js

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'admin'
});

module.exports = {
    get: function(){
        connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
            return rows;
        })
    }       
}
```

/routes/company.js

```
var Company    = require('../models/company')


var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/companies').get(function(req, res){

    console.log(Company.get());
    //res.json(Company.get());


})
```

I already tried some things, but I think this is how it should be.
But my `console.log` returns me `undefined`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

If I do:

```
 connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
                console.log(rows)
            })
```

It works.

What do I need to do (or study)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your get function returns `undefined` because you don't specify a return value.  You specify a return value for your callback function, but your outer function doesn't know or care about that.  If you want the behavior you expect, you need to pass in a callback to your `get` function to have access to the `rows` variable.

Try this:

```
 module.exports = {
    get: function(callback){
        connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
            // A 'node-style' callback will usually be callback(error, value)
            callback(null, rows);
        })
    }       
}
```

Your console.log will work if you do this:

```
Company.get(function(error, rows){
  console.log(rows);
}
```

For a general overview of asynchronous behavior in javascript, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your `get` function is calling an asynchronous function inside it. Where you're calling `return rows`, it's actually returning the rows to the anonymous function not the `get` function.

This is basically what you have:

```
module.exports = {
    get: function(){
        connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
            //This return is returning THIS function --^
            return rows;
        });

        return; //You're not returning anything. So it's undefined like just calling return.
    }       
}
```

What you want:

/model/company.js:

```
...

module.exports = {
    get: function(callback){
        connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
            callback(rows);
        })
    }       
}
```

/routes/company.js:

```
...

router.route('/companies').get(function(req, res){
    Company.get(function (rows) {
        console.log(rows);
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the json as follows

```
get: function(){
        connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
            res.json(rows);
        })
    }
```

Comment: If this is the case, he'd also need to pass in the `res` object.  In general, it's probably not a good practice to have your database module know about how the response object is going to work.